# Can prettier or other VSCode formatter be configured for YAML to omit line breaks after dashes in list syntax?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, prettier

I am writing yaml files to include in a project. Files of this type exist in the project already and list syntax looks like:

```
books:
  - title: "Harry Potter"
    author: "J. K. Rowling"
  - title: "Dune"
    author: "Frank Herbert"
```

I am using json2yaml to create a yaml from a json file and it shows lists like:

```
books:
  - 
    title: "Harry Potter"
    author: "J. K. Rowling"
  - 
    title: "Dune"
    author: "Frank Herbert"
```

I prefer to keep to the style of the existing files. Is there a setting in VSCode or prettier that takes care of this? Or what can I change in json2yaml to get the style of the converted files to match?

Comment: if you install the package `ruamel.yaml.cmd` you can convert JSON to YAML with `yaml json <filename>` and it will not have the unnecessary newline.

Comment: I did a find/replace to make the change. I will check out ruamel though.

Comment: @Anthon do you have a link for usage? I tried with myjson.json as filename and it only returned a json string not a yaml doc.

Comment: There seemed to be an error in the version on PyPI and I tested with a newer (local) version, which I now pushed to PyPI. With 0.6.4 you should be able to do the command from my first comment. (you will have to redirect the output to the YAML file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 'ruamel.yaml.cmd>=0.6.5' installed you can do:

```
yaml json input.json > output.yaml
```

as the following program shows:

```py
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

json_file = Path('input.json')
yaml_file = Path('output.yaml')
json_file.write_text("""\
{
  "books": [
    {
      "title": "Harry Potter",
      "author": "J. K. Rowling"
    },
    {
      "title": "Dune",
      "author": "Frank Herbert"
    }
  ]
}
""")

res = subprocess.check_output('yaml json input.json'.split(), encoding='utf-8')
print(res)
```

which gives:

```
books:
- author: J. K. Rowling
  title: Harry Potter
- author: Frank Herbert
  title: Dune
```

Comment: Getting error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'orjson' Can email you the stack at ruamel.eu?

Comment: No, need to get the stacktrace. Can you upgrade the package? (`pip install -U ruamel.yaml.cmd`)

Comment: Glas this helped, and apologies for the confusion. I obviously need to find some time to expand on the test cases for this package.